# Compile custom kernel and modules in Alpine Linux

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to build additional modules in Alpine Linux 3.15.

In order to do that, I have installed:

```
linux-virt-dev
```

needed for make menu config:

```
ncurses
ncurses-dev
ncurses-lib
```

After I run `make menuconfig`, I then wanted to do either `make all` or `make kernel && make modules`, but doing so results in:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:213: archheaders] Error 2
```

I was loosely following this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606073/how-to-build-kernel-modules-in-alpine-3-12

I am running the virtual linux kernel, so I've made that tweak.  I came across this document; however, shouldn't a kernel compile typically be get the source and then make kernel, modules, initrd and done?

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Custom_Kernel